Rails 7.1 Stack level too deep in partials and simpleform
After upgrading our rails stack from 7.0 to 7.1 i noticed these weird errors of stack level too deep even without much of a stack trace. It happens as far as i noticed, only whenever i have a simple form passing the form down to a partial.
as in here = render partial: 'form_general', locals: { f: form, plane: plane }

It seems to be very isolated to the passing of the f: form, what i tried is to blank the partial file completely ( remove the code inside ) and still pass the form, i get the error, if i also remove the f: form local to the partial, the error goes away.
Anyone else have anything like this happening?
edit.html.haml

= simple_form_for @plane do |form|
  = render 'form_general', locals: { f: form }

the partial can be blank and it will still throw the error
_form_general.html.haml
-# EMPTY



can you add content of _form and _form_general partials?

edited the initial question to reflect this

guys, as i wrote, it actually does not matter, i even isolated it down to having empty partial, and nothing else but passing simple form into the partial will make the error occur, even if _form is blank and contains nothing else

I updated _form to prevent confusion on this :D sorry.

Open issue on rails - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/52142

I just found the cause for this!
i had  gem 'meta_request' in my gemfile, this cause the error, after i removed it, i have no issue
